# Xamarin andorid avoid system terminating app even if it have been i background for at long time

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am building an app for a company that they want to run on their company phones, the app needs to send a GPS update to the company server every x time, and also it needs to check if they got any new orders.

And I got that to work just fine.

My problem is now that the android system sometimes terminates the "unused" apps.

It is very important for the company that the app ONLY stops if the user terminates it. Is there a way to accomplish that?

I am using Xamarin Android API 23

I know that Xamarin talks about sticky services, but I want the whole app to run sticky if it is possible.

Comment: use the alarmmanager to wake your app up every once in a while, instead of trying to keep the app alive all the time

Comment: Would this also be the right approach even if I need to check for incoming messages every sec, and send location at least every 25 sec?

(for incoming I use an event)

Comment: if you need to check for messages every second, then you should instead use a push mechanism from your server. You are basically going to drain the user's battery super fast by doing this constant polling

Comment: The battery drain is not a concern, as the mobile is mounted in a charger in the car 95% of the time. 

But battery drain do not seems that bad atm on my own phone. (running 12h + no problem)

But god to keep in mind. 
ATM the app have a rabbitMQ connection open, and then I have an event handler for incoming messages. Do you have an idea for a better approach? (The customers biggest requirement is that messages are received VERY FAST)

Do you have a good link for a god push mechanism?

Comment: I worked in a team that set up an xmpp server for pushing messages. it's pretty fast. I assume rabbitmq is quite fast too, but I never saw it used in a mobile app.

Comment: RabbitMQ is working fine after some tuning, when testing I get the "order" before I can remove my finger from the button on the phone.